# How do I add formulas to additional rows of my Google sheet automatically?

Tags: google-sheets

All my rows have the same formulas. I want it to be copied to the newly added rows automatically. Sheets provide us with 1000 rows initially and an another 1000 or so can be added subsequently as per requirement. I want sheets to automatically copy paste formulas to the newly added row.

Comment: You may want to consider the use of Arrayformula() instead of single-cell formulas. If you need more help, please share a copy of you spreadsheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LMxSLU8HmhcbadNxOXd87t_zp77RagGcvUUyeEm98uY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can arrayformula be used along with vlookup function also ? if yes, how is the syntax modified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't edit the sheet (because of protection on the sheet) but try clearing out alll contents of column T and then enter in T1

```
={"SPOT SURVEYOR'S MOBILE NO"; Arrayformula(if(len(S2:S), IFERROR(vlookup(S2:S,$EE$2:$EO,5,0)),))}
```

and see if that works?